# MySqlDataReader in C# has no rows

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqldatareader

I'm trying to develop a little user-user messaging system in C# (my first C# app) using a mysql database.

I know best practice would be to use something like EF for working with the database, but I'm writing this the "stupid" way just to get comfortable with the syntax.

I come from a vb background so I'm basically just converting what I normally do in vb and that's why I can't understand why, despite having a matching row in my database, the DataReader keeps coming back with no rows. See below:

```
    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Validate("Login");

        if (!IsValid)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (checkLogin())
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblErr.Text = "Invalid login attempt";
        }
    }

    protected Boolean checkLogin()
    {
        MySql db = new MySql();

        string sql = "select userid, firstname, lastname, ifnull(lastlogin, '') from users where email = @email and pass = @pass";

        List<MySqlParameter> args = new List<MySqlParameter>();
        args.Add(new MySqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@email", MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar, Size = 100, Value = txtEmail.Text });
        args.Add(new MySqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@pass", MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar, Size = 20, Value = txtPass.Text });

        MySqlDataReader dr = db.getReader(sql, args);

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            dr.Read();

            Session["userid"] = dr.GetInt32("userid");
            Session["firstname"] = dr.GetString("firstname");
            Session["lastname"] = dr.GetString("lastname");
            Session["lastlogin"] = dr.GetDateTime("lastlogin");

            dr.Close();

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The above code checks the user input against the database and returns a row if there are any rows in the table that match the user input...

Here's the code for the interaction with the database...

```
public class MySql
{
    static string connStr = "data source=localhost; initial catalog=mail; user id=root; password=Ly@12157114;";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

    public MySqlDataReader getReader(string sql, List<MySqlParameter> args)
    {
        if (args.Count == 0)
        {
            return getReader(sql);
        }
        else
        {
            return getReader(sql, args.ToArray());
        }
    }
    public MySqlDataReader getReader(string sql, MySqlParameter[] args = null)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);

        if (args != null)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(args);
        }

        conn.Open();

        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        conn.Close();

        return dr;
    }
}
```

I get no errors or any indication that something has gone wrong here and I'm positive there is data that match my input into the login fields.

Can anyone help me to understand why the DataReader keeps coming back empty?

Comment: A giant ORM like EF is not the only way to do data access. You should consider looking at a lightweight wrapper like [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) or [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/), since you've essentially ended up writing your own wrapper, which will no doubt evolve into solving the problems other wrappers have already solved. I can't see the bug you're having, but I can see ways to improve the code (eg, "using" statements are needed) but it's wasted effort, since as I said, Dapper/Petapoco/EF/etc have already solved this problem quite well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The connection of your data reader must be opened when you use it. The DataReader don't retrieve any data when you create it, it retrieves data when you use it. It can not retrieve your all database before you close the connection.

Comment: Okay, but isn't that what `conn.Open();` is supposed to take care of before `MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();` executes?

Comment: Marafol is right. You are closing the connection before you have read any of the rows. If you need to close the connection at this point, you should use a DataTable and fill it from the reader.

Comment: A datareader gives you a way to iterate along your query result (read only), but if you close your connection or use it for an other datareader or dataAdapter, you will lose your current result. For use a data reader you need an alive connection. You could use a dataAdapter and fill a DataTable with your result. You neither can use nested data reader with de same connection.

Comment: @maralfol I see, thanks :) Solved my issue. I'm giving it a +1 and answer

Comment: I think again this speaks to my earlier comment. If you're going to use ADO directly, use ADO directly. If you want a wrapper around ADO, use one of the many existing wrappers that have already learned and sorted this stuff out for you.